# Поэлементное соединение матриц

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

У меня есть 2 матрицы `numpy.array` одинакового размера:

```
[[a, b, c],
 [d, e, f]]

[[z, x, v],
 [r, t, y]]
```

Как соединить их поэлементно так, чтобы получилось:

```
[[[a,z],[b,x],[c,v]],
 [[d,r],[e,t],[f,y]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [np.dstack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```py
In [240]: a1 = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']])

In [241]: a2 = np.array([['z', 'x', 'v'], ['r', 't', 'y']])

In [242]: res = np.dstack((a1, a2))

In [243]: res
Out[243]:
array([[['a', 'z'],
        ['b', 'x'],
        ['c', 'v']],

       [['d', 'r'],
        ['e', 't'],
        ['f', 'y']]], dtype='<U1')
```